# Get SPO sites using MS Graph API powershell not working

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to get all SharePoint Online sites' name and url via PowerShell using MS Graph API, but it's not seem to be working. That's all I get from the request:

`@{@odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites; value=System.Object[]}`

The application I use have all the needed Application type API permissions (Sites.Read, Sites.ReadWrite.All) with admin consent.

Do you have any idea why my script not working?

The code:

```
$TenantID = 'xxxxxxxxx.ONMICROSOFT.COM'
$ApplicationId = "xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
$ApplicationSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$body = @{
    'resource'      = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
    'client_id'     = $ApplicationId
    'client_secret' = $ApplicationSecret
    'grant_type'    = "client_credentials"
    'scope'         = "openid"
}

$ClientToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantid)/oauth2/token" -Body $body -ErrorAction Stop
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $($ClientToken.access_token)" }


$AllSites = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*" -Headers $headers -Method Get 

Write-Host $AllSites
```

I've also tried these URIs:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites$select=siteCollection,webUrl&$filter=siteCollection/root%20ne%20null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Write-Host cmdlet's primary purpose is to produce
> for-(host)-display-only output, such as printing colored text like
> when prompting the user for input in conjunction with Read-Host.
> Write-Host uses the ToString() method to write the output. By
> contrast, to output data to the pipeline, use Write-Output or implicit
> output.

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.2)

This mean that your output is transformed for display purposes. Where you see `System.Object[]`, there is actually data in there just waiting for you.

Based on your current results, your query look good.
Just do not use `Write-Host` and dig into the object as needed.
To get the site names, just use `$AllSites.Value.Name`

```
$AllSites = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*" -Headers $headers -Method Get

# Return site names
$AllSites.Value.Name
```

If you need to get additional information from each return you can loop into them, like this to do whatever you need. Here is a custom display of the site name along with an arbitrary index and the associated URL

```
$index = 0
# Will display results like
# 0: SiteName - www.contoso.sharepoint.com/SiteUrl
foreach ($Site in $AllSites.Value) {
    Write-Host "$($index.ToString().PadRight(3,' ')): $($Site.Name) - " -NoNewline 
    Write-Host $site.webUrl -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $index += 1
}
```

Also, here is an additional reference when working with Azure Graph API that will confirm your requests are working as expected: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer